# Hybrid oriented multigraph networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Using networkx, is there a way to make a multigraph with directed edges AND bidirectional edges?

I can't use 2 oriented edges instead of a bidirectional one because they mean different things in my graph.
`networkx.MultiDiGraph()` only alows directional edges and `networkx.MultiGraph()` only alows bidirectional edges.

Comment: You can't have mixed directed and undirected edges in a networkx graph at this point.   Depending on your problem data and what algorithms you want to use there might be a way to address your problem using edge labels to distinguish edge types.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the confirmation. I only want to use `networkx.has_path(Graph, node1, node2)`

Comment: And is that possible to have an Undirected multigraph, and make a directed subgraph out of it ?

Comment: If you want to check to see if there is a path between node1 and node2 why doesn't it work to use 2 oriented edges for an undirected edge?

Comment: this was an issue for my representation,but I might just go with that, and adapte later for the vizualisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to draw the nodes, labels, then draw edges twice once from a graph and the other from the diGraph over top of the undirected or split it into two sets.

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G) #directed
nx.draw_networkx_edges(H) #undirected
```

If that fails, you can play around with edgewidth to cover up the directed and scale up the ones you want seen.